# Debug set always restart container docker

Tags: docker

How can I debug docker container that I set to always restart.

I have a container that launch nodejs app, with a 
CMD ["nodemon", "/usr/src/app/app.js »] that work very well on other container but not on the new one i created it says with docker logs containerName :

Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

See "nodemon --help" for more.

How can I connect to the container to have more informations than logs, for example see some config file or if my nodejs files have been copied.

I didn’t find a way : I would like to use docker exec -it bash and navigate in my docker but because it is always restarting I cannot. How to debug this kind of container ?

EDIT : i use the CMD["bash"] but when i use docker exec -it bash i doesn't work

[image]

Because the container keep restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a new image base on your container image, and a different starting script (one which runs the node command for testing, and then opens a bash for instance)

You could need to COPY that script

```
COPY myscript /usr/local/bin
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/myscript"]
```

That way, you can test your current image as wrapped in a test image.

You can even only use bash in that new image

```
CMD["bash"]
```

And launch the command manually.

For that, you would need to run that image with:

```
docker run -it --rm myNewImage
```

That will open an *interactive* bash session.

Comment: If i do 
CMD ["nodemon", "/usr/src/app/app.js"]
CMD ["bash"] 
at the end of my file the container keep restarting because i set always restart and i am not able to go through this container again and explore it with docker exec -it bash. But when i use my first nodejs container it keep running. I need to remove the restart always ?

Comment: @user3343399 I would recommend wrapping a sequence of commands in a script and COPY it in your image (see my edited answer). Or you can simply launch a bash directly, and type manually the problematic command.

Comment: I prefer to launch a bash directly, and type manually the problematic command. But how i use the docker exec -it bash but i doesn't work as with the other running containers

Comment: @user3343399 you won't need to use docker exac with that new image: when running it (with `docker run -it --rm`), it will open a bash and won't quit until you quit the bash. You can type the command in there.

Comment: Thanks i never used docker run -it --rm before thanks.

Comment: @user3343399 Great. I have added that `docker run` command in the answer for more visibility.